# Simplest way to secure Azure Web Role WCF service

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles

Using latest VS 2013 and Azure SDK 2.4, I've created a Web Role and a WCF service in it.
This service will be consumed by a standard generated .NET service reference client proxy.

I am trying to figure out what is the *simplest* way to secure this WCF service. I mean securing the authentication can not be hacked easy way, like clear text pwd etc.

Some additional info about the use case:

- There will be only one user
- It is completely OK to store any secret in client side (like username/pwd or certificate) because the client app will run in a secured place
- I just would like to prevent my service to be accessed by the public. Only my secured place running client app should access it, I would like no more no less.

So I am googling the web, and more I read more I confused and overwhelmed with the options and possibilities what I do not need I think. When searching for client certificate I find overcomplicated federated auth methods with server side temp certs etc what I am not sure my simple use case requires.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the minus. Besides the one click effort you've invested any chance you wrote some comments?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to restrict access then I would look at client certificates. Configuring azure for client certificates seems quite complex to detail in a single SO post so I'll refer you to this blog post [client-certificates-in-windows-azure](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/applisec/2013/04/07/client-certificates-in-windows-azure/) and I'll summarize below [I used this myself recently so I know it works]

In essence you can make your own certificates using `makecert` [NOTE: you may want an official SSL cert for your site and only use self-signed for your client certificates.]

You then configure your site to accept client certs - normally I'd use `appcmd.exe` and a startup task but as the blog post points out your site is not ready so instead you need to add this to your webrole `OnStart` method [I actually went down the `appcmd.exe` path initially and was very confused].

```
using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
   try
   {
       var siteName = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web";
       var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
       var accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", siteName);
       accessSection["sslFlags"] = @"SslNegotiateCert";

       serverManager.CommitChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        ...
   }
}
```

In the `CertificateAuthHandler` you can than validate the certificate and if you want (and I recommend) that the client certificate being sent is from your expected CA (if self-signed) or that the thumbprint of the certificate is the one you expect (if there is only going to be one) or a combination of the above.